# How to retrieve a text present in text box as getText() wouldn't work using selenium

Tags: selenium

Here is the Html:

```
 <html>
       <head>
            </head>
                 <body contenteditable="true" style="margin: 0px; padding: 8px; font-family: monospace; box-sizing: border-box;">count(< Field >,< Filter >)
          </body>
       </html>
```

How can i read `count(< Field >,< Filter >)` from body as `getText()` returns null?

I am using css so what should be the css to locate the body tag?

Comment: You should add to the question the code you tried.

Comment: @S Mahapatra what issue you are facing. i have tried code written in below answer it is working fine.

Comment: <iframe src="about:blank" seamless="true" class="editor-frame" title="Rich Text Editor" style="height: 142px;"> </iframe><html><head></head><body contenteditable="true" style="margin: 0px; padding: 8px; font-family: monospace; box-sizing: border-box;"></body></html>

Comment: Thanks a lot @MuhammadUSman for your comments.I have pasted the html above.Sorry it is not properly formatted.Body tag shows the text that appear when we select some item from drop down and click on insert.I just want to fetch the data from the text box which appear in body tag.In this case i can't able to read the text by getText() method.

Comment: @S Mahapatra html you added in comments is not proper and full html. But it is show you are using iframe. You have to get iframe first and then swith on ifram then get inner Element of iframe. this is the way to access elements inside iframe. Know you edit question and paste proper html or try to switch on ifram then use xPath to get elements which inside iframe.

Comment: @S Mahapatra one more thing there is no text box in your question/comment html. Give a full html which contain what you want to access or get, then may b i can help you further.
Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadUSman,Thanks a lot for your comment.Now it is working when i move the focus.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested below code. it is working fine and getting your required text.

```
 public  static void getBodyText()    {
FirefoxDriver driver;
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Muhammad USman/Desktop/testit.html");
String text= driver.findElementByTagName("body").getText();
    System.out.println(text);


}
```

just call this function in main and give your url/file path.
if any issue then let me know.